# How to create a 2D double array with column of ones

Tags: java, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

I am in need of computing column sums in java using apache's RealMatrix. This would work like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.MatrixUtils;

double[][] values = {{1.0, 2.0}, {3.0, 4.0}, {5.0, 6.0}};
RealMatrix matrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(values);

MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][]{{1, 1, 1}}).multiply(matrix)
>> Array2DRowRealMatrix{{9.0,12.0}}
```

However, I would like to make it general when it comes to declaring **ones** in

```
MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][]{{1, 1, 1}})
```

Is there a way to pre-declare the number of ones I want inside a curly bracket?

Say I want `numberOfOnes = 10`, then:

```
MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][]{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}})
```

I am struggling to find a way to make this general. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(double%5B%5D,%20double)):

```
double[][] m = new double[rows][cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    Arrays.fill(m[i], 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method to process each row separately:

```java
double[][] m = new double[rows][];
Arrays.setAll(m, i -> {
    double[] row = new double[cols];
    Arrays.fill(row, 1.0);
    return row;
});
```